# Yaml - how to break very long string

Tags: yaml

I have an entry in my yaml file that looks like this

```
my_key:['short string', 'thisisaverylongstringthatcontains.,specialcharacterssoI havetousequotes,andI wanttobreakintomultiplelines']
```

My very long string can't contain spaces, and I am worried if I simply use newline, it will get converted to space.
What is the cleanest, simplest way to break down that second string across multiple lines for easier readability and convenience?

Comment: It's an exact duplicate. You can use a string quoted with `>` anywhere YAML expects a string.  Just because you have  a list of strings doesn't impact your ability to use that syntax.

Comment: Yes, actually; you'd be surprised at how often that happens around here.

Comment: Your question is answered by [this answer to the same duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43354815/147356).

Comment: "So how did you expect me to find this answer near the bottom of the page?" Having had several people point out that this question was a duplicate, I expected you, as someone familiar with the site, to thoroughly read through the answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key  : ['short string', "this is a very long string 
                         that I want to break into
                         multiple lines"]
```

Have you tried just inserting a newline? This is valid YAML.

If you don't want spaces, add `\` to the end of each line.

```
key  : ['short string', "this is a very long string\
                         that I want to break into\
                         multiple lines"]
```

Comment: Sorry, my very long string can't contain spaces, and I'm worried about new line getting converted to space.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you please edit your answer with respect to the updates I've made to my question?